# EXPORT AS XLSX format python google sheet api

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api

may I know what I need to do to export the file in google sheet as xlsx format?

My code below is working but I need to save the file also into xlsx format...... :(

**Here's my code:**

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import gsheets

pdkey = "keypd.json"
url = f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MCkqb_123123123123asdasdada/edit#gid=0"

SCOPE = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
CREDS = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(pdkey, SCOPE)

sheets = gsheets.Sheets(CREDS)
sheet = sheets.get(url)
sheet[0].to_csv("/root/xlsx/SAMPLE.csv")
```

Comment: When I tested my proposed script, no error occurs and XLSX file can be created. But, from your reply of `no data since it has 9kb file size only`, I thought that when the data in the file can be confirmed, the reason for the issue might be found. But, from `Unfortunately, I cannot give you the data in the xlsx file since the file has only 1kb and unable to open it`, I cannot see the data in the file. So in the current stage, I cannot understand OP's issue. But, when I could find the reason for it, I would like to modify my answer.

Comment: Now, I think that in the current stage, my answer was not useful for OP's situation. So I have to delete my answer. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: No, thank you for your help atleast I have an idea on how to extract an xlsx file.

You may post your solution so I can get back to it. Thanks @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot still replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. When I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: You may post again your previous modified code here, so I can get back to it. Thank you @Tanaike

Comment: access_token = CREDS.create_delegated(CREDS._service_account_email).get_access_token().access_token
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + my_sheet_url + "/export?mimeType=application%2Fvnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
res = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token})


with open("sample.xlsx", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res.content)


here's the modification I did.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike thank you for your modification I already figure out what is issue.

great help! cheers!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your replying, I reopened my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about exporting the Spreadsheet with the export method of Drive API? When this is reflected in your script it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
sheets = gsheets.Sheets(CREDS)
sheet = sheets.get(url)
sheet[0].to_csv("/root/xlsx/SAMPLE.csv")
```

##### To:

```
access_token = CREDS.create_delegated(CREDS._service_account_email).get_access_token().access_token
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + spreadsheet_id + "/export?mimeType=application%2Fvnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
res = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token})

# If you want to create the XLSX data as a file, you can use the following script.
with open("sample.xlsx", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```

- In this script, please add `import requests`.
- In this modified script, the Spreadsheet is exported as XLSX data using the method of export in Drive API. The access token is retrieved from the service account.

#### Reference:

- [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)

Comment: I tried to modified my script with your exact script above but it looks like the extracted xlsx file is corrupted or no data since it has 9kb file size only, maybe there something wrong with my modification on the script?

I added also the import request above the script and I delete the csv script then I copy and paste your modified script then execute to my server.

Comment: @rodskies Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I tested my proposed script, the XLSX file can be created. I apologize for this sitaution. So in your current situation, can I ask you about the detail of the data in the created file of `corrupted or no data since it has 9kb file size only`? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: 1kb only, apologize for the confusion.

here's the error when I open the extracted xlsx file

"Excel cannot open the file 'sample.xlsx' because the file format of file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file"

Comment: @rodskies Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `Excel cannot open the file 'sample.xlsx' because the file format of file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file`, from this situation, I had wanted to confirm the data in the file. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot give you the data in the xlsx file since the file has only 1kb and unable to open it, but based on the previous extracted file with csv format the extracted file size has 2,466kb with data.

Comment: @rodskies When I tested my proposed script, no error occurs and XLSX file can be created. But, from your reply of `no data since it has 9kb file size only`, I thought that when the data in the file can be confirmed, the reason for the issue might be found. But, from `Unfortunately, I cannot give you the data in the xlsx file since the file has only 1kb and unable to open it`, I cannot see the data in the file. So in the current stage, I cannot understand OP's issue. But, when I could find the reason for it, I would like to modify my answer.

Comment: @rodskies Now, I think that in the current stage, my answer was not useful for OP's situation. So I have to delete my answer. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike May I know how to add date as file naming convention?

Comment: @rodskies Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately from your new question of `May I know how to add date as file naming convention?`, I cannot understand whether my proposed answer could have resolved your issue. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69877757/date-as-part-of-file-name-nming-convention-for-gsheet-api-exported-xlsx-file-usi

Hi @Tanaike here's the link for the details

Comment: @
@rodskies Thank you for replying. I think that `stackoverflow.com/questions/69877757/… Hi @Tanaike here's the link for the details` is your new question. I wanted to have asked whether my answer could have resolved [your this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69776494). I apologize for this.

Comment: yes, this issue is already resolved thank you for your help.

the link I posted is new question I hope we can resolve this as well.