# Date as part of file name nming convention for Gsheet API exported xlsx file using python

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, pygsheets

May I know what function I need to add/replace on my python script, here's my issue I have exported xlsx file from gsheet API to my server and I need to add an generic filename with file name and date (ex. FILENAME20211107.xlsx)

here's my code:

```
  with open("/xlsx/FILENAME.xlsx", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```

Comment: In your situation, from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69776494), you want to give the same filename of the file on Google Drive by changing the file extension. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, the goal is to set File naming convention using date in the script for example.

If I run the script the extracted file from google api will be automatically named like this format "filename_202111107.xlsx"

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `the goal is to set File naming convention using date in the script for example. If I run the script the extracted file from google api will be automatically named like this format "filename_202111107.xlsx"`, you want to use the specific filename like `filename_202111107.xlsx` in your script. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```py
import datetime # Please add this.
import os # Please add this.

path = "/xlsx/"
prefix = "sampelName"
suffix = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
filename = prefix + "_" + suffix + ".xlsx"
v = os.path.join(path, filename)
print(v) # <--- /xlsx/sampelName_20211108.xlsx

with open(v, 'wb') as f:
  f.write(res.content)
```

When above script is run, `v` is `/xlsx/sampelName_20211108.xlsx`.

#### Note:

- In your comment, you use `202111107` of `filename_202111107.xlsx`. In this case, when the script is run on November 7, 2021, you want to use `20211107`. I understood like this. In your question, I understood that you might want to use `20211107` instead of `202111107`.

Comment: Apologize for the late reply, the script is working if the file is not too big, but when I tried to larger gsheet I got an error it says that its to large to be exported... :( I hope you can help me.

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "exportSizeLimitExceeded",
    "message": "This file is too large to be exported."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "This file is too large to be exported."
 }
}

Comment: @rodskies Thank you for replying. I thought that your situation might be the same with [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761333). I apologize for this. In that case, is this my answer useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66344211/7108653

Comment: yes the date is working thank you! maybe I should file new ticket for another issue, by the way apologize again for the late reply I'm on vacation these past weeks. Thank you again @Tanaike

Comment: @rodskies Thank you for replying. It's no problem. Thank you, too.

Comment: I hope you can help me again for another issue, here's the link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70013643/python-gsheet-export-limitation-error-exportsizelimitexceeded

Comment: @rodskies I will check it.