# python Gsheet export limitation error "exportSizeLimitExceeded"

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pygsheets

Trying to export a file from gsheet using python and I encountered this issue, may I know what I need to add on my script?

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "exportSizeLimitExceeded",
    "message": "This file is too large to be exported."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "This file is too large to be exported."
 }
}
```

Heres my script when I got the error

```
path = "/root/xlsx/"
prefix = "Remastered"
suffix = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
filename = prefix + "_" + suffix + ".xlsx"
v = os.path.join(path, filename)
print(v)
 
with open(v, 'wb') as f:
  f.write(res.content)
```

Comment: In this case, in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. Or, although I cannot test this, in your situation, for example, when the URL is changed to `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?exportFormat=xlsx&id=###YourSpreadsheetId###`, will your issue be removed?

Comment: May I know if there is a way that we can modify the script that can able to export a spreadsheet with no limitation?

Comment: I change the url using this code but the issue change from "exportsizelimitexceeded" to Not found.

May I know if I was correct on my modification?

>>>>>  url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?exportFormat=xlsx&id=SpreadsheetID"

Comment: Hi I figured it out what I need to change :D the first solution above my first comment is working. Thank you again! great @Tanake

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could understand that when the URL is modified to `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?exportFormat=xlsx&id=###YourSpreadsheetId###`, your issue was resolved. I'm glad for it. I thought that this might be useful for other users. So I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0):

Please modify `url` and test it again.

#### From:

```
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + "sdfasdasdasdasdadsa_1231_123" + "/export?mimeType=application%2Fvnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
```

#### To:

```
url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?exportFormat=xlsx&id=###YourSpreadsheetId###"
```